# Django REST framework queryset object has no attribute pk

Tags: python, django

I am building a larger Django-based web app, but I have a blocking issue with an API view that should return some data.

I the application I have a model (`mail.models.Message`) and a matching serializer and viewset.

For a reporting feature, I need to get filtered set of results and have therefoer created a seperate rest_framework.views.APIView for the purpose of the reporting. The model is located in one app and the reporting is in another app.

Here is the model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
class Meta:
    ordering = ('-timestamp',)
    get_latest_by = 'timestamp'

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    from_address = models.CharField("From", max_length=511, blank=True, default="", db_index=True)
    from_domain = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="", db_index=True)
    to_address = models.CharField("To", max_length=511, blank=True, default="", db_index=True)
    to_domain = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="", db_index=True)
    subject = models.TextField(blank=True, default="", db_index=True)
    client_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField("Client IP", db_index=True, null=True)
    mailscanner_hostname = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    spam_score = models.DecimalField(db_index=True, default=0.00, max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    mcp_score = models.DecimalField(db_index=True, default=0.00, max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    size = models.FloatField(default=0)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    mailq_id = models.TextField("Mailqueue identification", null=True)
    whitelisted = models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=False)
    blacklisted = models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=False)
    is_spam = models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=False)
    is_mcp = models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=False)
    is_rbl_listed = models.BooleanField("Is RBL listed", db_index=True, default=False)
    quarantined = models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=False)
    infected = models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=False)
    released = models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + "[" + str(self.from_address) + " to " + str(self.to_address) + "]"
```

And the matching serializer:

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = (
            'id',
            'url',
            'from_address',
            'from_domain',
            'to_address',
            'to_domain',
            'subject',
            'client_ip',
            'mailscanner_hostname',
            'spam_score',
            'timestamp',
            'size',
            'token',
            'whitelisted',
            'blacklisted',
            'is_spam',
            'is_rbl_listed',
            'quarantined',
            'infected'
        )
```

The model has a lot of indexes on it to improve the performance search and filtering, but I have excluded these.

For the reporting, I have created this special view:

```
class MessageListApiView(ReportApiView):
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
    queryset = Message.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            filters = self.request.data
            return MessageQuerySetFilter.filter(MessageQuerySetFilter, self.queryset, filters)
        else:
            return self.queryset


    def post(self, request, format=None):
        filters = request.data
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = MessageSerializer(qs, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data, 200)
```

In `get_queryset`, I use a special class and the only purpose of that class is to apply the appropriate filtering on the queryset and return it. Doing some testing, I have found the issue occurs when I have to return the `Response`.

I get this traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/reports/messages/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kenneth/Code/mailware/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/kenneth/Code/mailware/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "/Users/kenneth/Code/mailware/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/kenneth/Code/mailware/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kenneth/Code/mailware/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kenneth/Code/mailware/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 494, in dispatch
response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/kenneth/Code/mailware/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 454, in handle_exception
self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/kenneth/Code/mailware/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 491, in dispatch
response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kenneth/Code/mailware/src/reports/views.py", line 44, in post
return Response(serializer.data, 200)
  File "/Users/kenneth/Code/mailware/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 537, in data
ret = super(Serializer, self).data
  File "/Users/kenneth/Code/mailware/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 262, in data
self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/Users/kenneth/Code/mailware/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 504, in to_representation
ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/Users/kenneth/Code/mailware/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 376, in to_representation
url = self.get_url(value, self.view_name, request, format)
  File "/Users/kenneth/Code/mailware/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 312, in get_url
lookup_value = getattr(obj, self.lookup_field)
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'
[19/Jan/2018 20:05:24] "POST /api/reports/messages/ HTTP/1.1" 500 16389
```

The above `APIView` class inherits a custom base class, which is what inherits the `rest_framework.views.APIView` class. This class is called  `ReportApiView` and simply sets the `paginator_class` and the `permission_class`

```
class ReportApiView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    pagination_class = PageNumberPaginationWithPageCount
```

In the `MessageListApiView` `post` method it seems to go wrong in the `return` line, but I cannot find the reason why it is not working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `many=True` to serializer queryset:

```
serializer = MessageSerializer(qs, many=True, context={'request': request})
```

Comment: Thank you. Must have forgotten that one :)

Comment: If you want to test this on the shell, then you will have to pass `None` for the request as this: `serializer = MessageSerializer(qs, many=True, context={'request': None})` which will return a relative url

Answer (score 0):

just you need to add many = true in serializer
serializer = userSerializer.UserSeria(user,data=request.data,many=True)

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, for the ones coming here from Google, my problem was this one:

The model I wanted to serialize had a field containing `unique=True` in it. The multiple data I sent to the Serializer (with `many=True`) were not unique (already in db), and instead of having an error telling me this, the `"'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'"` was thrown which is really confusing. Anyway, after getting rid of the uniqueness, my code works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a nested serializer, and the parent serializer has a model which has `unique_together constraint? See below on how to overriding the` get_unique_together_validators` method to disable unique together checks, because the instance is not passed into nested serializer, and hence fails the check

```py
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Foo
        fields = '__all__'
        list_serializer_class = FooListSerializer

    def get_unique_together_validators(self):
        """Overriding method to disable unique together checks, because the instance is not passed into nested serializer, and hence fails the check"""
        return []
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue after adding many=True, finally by making the below change it worked.

```
class Meta:
       extra_kwargs = {"id": {"validators": []}}
```